# Sandbox, App store and "Private Frameworks"?

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, sandbox

- I have built-and-submitted an app since early 2012 (before the Sandbox thing became obligatory) and I'm thinking of re-submitting it (with fixes), which practically means it will *have* to comply with the new terms.
- The app executes in the background (pipes, processes, etc) a utility residing in the `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/` folder

**Does *that* qualify as "using Private Frameworks"?**

Comment: You know the worst thing that could possibly happen is that they reject that version of the app, right?  You don't get a permanent ban from the app store for sending in an app they don't approve.

Comment: @nhgrif I'm currently selling 43 apps on the store. So, yes. I do know that. The thing is that there is nothing more frustrating than wasting time working on an app that - by its very nature - simply can*not* be  accepted, ever. And the whole Sandbox thing is nerve-wrecking, by definition. (At least for me, given that several of my apps are System-oriented utilities). That's why I'm asking... :-)

Comment: Do you mean private frameworks were allowed before the sandbox era?  In 2011, they rejected our applications a few times by saying one or more private API were used when in fact there was none.

Comment: @ElTomato Hmm, that sounds interesting. So, they didn't? (That sounds rather cool, since the specific app I'm talking about had already been approved like 10 times...)